# rails active record associations sql behavior

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 models:

```
# models/car.rb
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model
end
```

and

```
# models/manufacturer.rb
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end
```

When I'm executing command in rails console `Car.find(1).manufacturer` it shows me that one more sql query was executed `SELECT manufacturers.* FROM manufacturers WHERE manufacturers.id = 54 LIMIT 1`,

so I am interested is it usual (for production, first of all) behavior, when a lot of sql queries being executed just to get some object property? what about performance?

**UPDATE, ANSWER:**
I got an answer from another source: I was told it's "necessary evil" as a payment for abstraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a "necessary evil" and your intuition that the second query is needless is correct. What you need to do is use `:include`/`includes` to tell Rails to do a `JOIN` to get the associated objects in the same `SELECT`. So you could do this:

```
Car.find 1, :include => :manufacturer

# or, in Rails 3 parlance:

Car.includes(:manufacturer).find 1
```

Rails calls this "eager loading" and you can [read more about it in the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) (scroll down to or Ctrl+F for "Eager loading of associations").

If you *always* want to eager-load the associated objects you can declare [`default_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-default_scope) in your model:

```
class Car
  belongs_to :manufacturer

  default_scope :include => :manufacturer

  # or Rails 3:

  default_scope includes(:manufacturer)
end
```

However you shouldn't do this unless you really need the associated Manufacturer *every time* you show a Car record.